# Admob Plugin Smartface 4.3 enable from the project deail for IOS

Tags: admob, smartface.io

I am trying to enable admob for the new version of Smartface 4.3 but it is disabled from project setting. And admob is not visible on Xcode product.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can download iOS Admob plugin from http://smartface.io/AdMob.rar

You just need to extract this archive folder to C:\Program Files (x86)\Smartface\Smartface App Studio 4.3\Data\Plugins

I guess that it will work now.

Comment: No! It did not work! The project settings option enabled admob, published for ios but the project created for ios is not validating by missing directories "../Plugins" and ../Smartface/smflibs/GoogleAdMob"

Comment: Did you installed nodeJS ?

ıt uses nodeJS to exporting files, I guess the problem is about it.

Comment: I solved by changing library destination folder manually from Xcode. The xcode export admob library location incorrectly defined or  the library folder incorrectly located.